# How to get rid of the black around my UIImage?

Tags: uiview, uiimage

How to get rid of the black around my UIImage? (shown in link below)

```
UIView *myView  = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
CCUIViewWrapper *wrapper = [CCUIViewWrapper wrapperForUIView:myView];

UIColor *background = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alert_background.png"]]; 
myView.backgroundColor = background;

wrapper.contentSize = CGSizeMake(293,180);
wrapper.position = ccp(-90,190);
[wrapper setRotation:90.0];

[self addChild:wrapper];
```

http://img857.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110312at153.png/

Answer (score 0):

try setting the opaque value of the view to NO

```
myView.opaque = NO;
```

This means that the view isn't expected to fill its bounds.

nonono

Comment: If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it.